# JBuilder template not rendering in browser (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I have two resources - let's call them Experiments and Measurements (an experiment has many measurements). When I edit an experiment (adding measurements that are associated with it), I'm able to persist data to the database - however, after the data saves, the browser remains on the Edit view (rather than rendering the Show view as I'd hoped). In the Terminal I'm able to see

"**Rendered experiments/show.json.jbuilder (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 9.8ms | ActiveRecord: 26.7ms)**"

From my experiments controller:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @experiment.update(experiment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @experiment, notice: 'Experiment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @experiment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @experiment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end
```

Here's my show.json.jbuilder view:

```
json.extract! @experiment, :id, :name, :description, :created_at, :updated_at
```

Any thoughts on why this view wouldn't be rendered in the browser? Thanks